# undefined method deserialize, for work added outside of my rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

We are working on a scheduler to schedule jobs for our rails application. We want to reduce the memory footprint and cpu usage this ruby script takes when it schedules so we are building it as separate project. Items are getting added to queue without any issue, but when they are executed by sidekiq they result in the following error.

```
undefined method `deserialize' for #<SummarizationStartAllJob:0x007f7fc4183080>
```

The code for the project is as follows:

```
require_relative 'sidekiq_redis_jobs'
require 'redis'
require 'json'

redis = Redis.new(:url => "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0")
msg = SidekiqjJobMessage.generate(class_name: "SummarizationStartAllJob", arguments: [], queue: 'summarization')
redis.sadd("queue", "summarization")
redis.lpush("queue:summarization", JSON.dump(msg))
```

`SidekiqjJobMessage`

```
require 'securerandom'

module SidekiqjJobMessage
  def self.generate(class_name:, arguments: [], queue: 'default')
    queue_name = "queue:#{queue}"
    msg = {
        "class" => 'ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper',
        "wrapped" => class_name,
        "queue" => queue_name,
        "args" => [{
          'job_class' => class_name,
          'job_id' => SecureRandom.hex(),
          'queue_name' => queue_name,
          'arguments' => arguments,
          'locale'=>'en'}], 
        'retry' => false,
        'jid' => SecureRandom.hex(12),
        'created_at' => Time.now.to_f,
        'enqueued_at' => Time.now.to_f
    }
  end
end
```

The message that is generated and added to the queue (redis)

```
{
  "class"       => "ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper",
  "wrapped"     => "SummarizationStartAllJob", "queue" => "queue:summarization",
  "args"        => [{ "job_class"  => "SummarizationStartAllJob",
                      "job_id"     => "f9fc7143bacd638d61938fcd74a81f21",
                      "queue_name" => "queue:summarization",
                      "arguments"  => [],
                      "locale"     => "en" }],
  "retry"       => false,
  "jid"         => "58565f2cf407de4fbc6d5013",
  "created_at"  => 1505988923.1029198,
  "enqueued_at" => 1505988923.102925
}
```

Message inserted by `SummarizationStartAllJob.perform_async` (parsed as json, for readability)

```
{
   "class":"SummarizationStartAllJob",
   "args":[

   ],
   "retry":true,
   "queue":"summarization",
   "backtrace":true,
   "jid":"d5b9d38f39bff95acee0dc61",
   "created_at":1505989631.233542,
   "enqueued_at":1505989631.242933
}
```

Comment: Your `SummarizationStartAllJob` doesn't have `deserialize` method. Is it an active job?

Comment: `SidekiqWorker` should i make it an `active job?`. It does run properly when i do `SummarizationStartAllJob.perform_async` in my rails console.

Comment: then, I guess, your manual metadata building code is missing something. Can you diff it with what `perform_async` produces?

Comment: My guess as well, but can't put a finger on it. :(

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have added the JSON content which is generated with my code.

Comment: Yes, now add one from perform_async. Also check that they are placed to the same queue, etc.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Do you know the command to get the message from queue. I am not aware of that.

Comment: The queue is a redis list. Using `redis-cli` and redis commands should be enough. [`LRANGE`](https://redis.io/commands/lrange), for example. Also there must be sidekiq api method for this, but I never learned it.

Comment: Got it, updating the question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thank you, that fixed it. My mistake from the source in which I got the Message format. can you please write and answer so that I can thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your enqueuing metadata generation code does not accurately reflect what happens when you do `MyJob.perform_async`. You should compare the two outputs and find where yours is different.